# Multiple animations are messed up

Tags: swift

In collection view I have cells with image for every cell.
When the delegates of the collection being called, I set a different animation for every cell image according to data.

Every new cell that being added, I **remove** all other cells and reload the data of the collection.

What happens is that after I add a few cells, say cell 1 has stretch animation and cell 3 has scale animation, then cell 1 get stretch+scale .

```
      func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
        {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FlowViewCell
            cell.image.image=UIImage(named: moduleImage as String)
            animate(moduleAnimation, image: cell.image)
             ....


            func animate (kind:NSString, image:UIImageView)
            // here I check what animation to apply (different between cells)

           // *** can be 
          CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
          //**** or
          UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.Repeat, .CurveEaseOut, .Autoreverse], animations: {         
                image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.15, 1.0)
```

Is there anything I can do to clear stuff? I think the reusable cells has something to do with it.

**EDIT**:
Have tried : `cell.image.image=nil` , no success .

Comment: Because cells are reused?

Comment: @matt thats right, but I remove all of them every time I load a new cell, and reload again. I was thinking that removing a view is enough to clear all its animations. Is there a solution?

Comment: Don't ask me; your code reads like nonsense to me (missing curly-braces etc.) so I've no idea what you're even doing. But when the wrong cell is affected by something it's usually because you're not managing cell reuse correctly.

Comment: Ok I will not ask you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it with this :

```
    let index = data.count-1
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: index, inSection: 0)
    collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
```

One should not use the `reloadData` function because there is no guarantee it will use the same cells again, and its not that good for performance, so instead update the cell that relevant.